# Exact meaning of the continuous at a point(Topology version)

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I've known the definition of the continuity like the below

$f : X \to Y$ is  continuous at $p \in X$

For every open set $V_{f(p)}$, $\exists$ $U_p s.t. f(U_p) \subset V_{f(p)}$

(Here the $V_{f(p)}$, $U_p$ are open sets including $f(p)$ and $p$ respectively)

---

There are two cases I interpreted

(1)  $\exists U_p$ $s.t.$ $ f(U_p) \subset \forall V_{f(p)}$

(For all $V_{f(p)}$, there is a $U_p$ satisfying the $ f(U_p) \subset V_{f(p)}$  regardless of what the $V_{f(p)}$ are. )

(2)  $\exists U_p$ $s.t.$ $ f(U_p) \subset$  **each**  $\forall$$V_{f(p)}$

(For all $V_{f(p)}$, there is a $U_p$  satisfying $ f(U_p) \subset V_{f(p)}$  corresponding the each $V_{f(p)}$)

So Between (1) and (2), What is the exact meaning of the continuity at the point? I'm really confused which one is correct.

Thanks.

Comment: The second: to each open set in $Y$ that contains $f(p)$ corresponds an open set in $X$ that contains $p$ such that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct meaning: for every open set $V$ containing $f(p)$, there is an open set $U$ containing $p$ (so usually **depending on $V$**) such that $f[U] \subseteq V$. So we can get any "accuracy" approximating $f(p)$, by getting "close enough" to $p$. We pick $U$ around $p$ based on $V$ around $f(p)$. So your second formulation comes closer. The metric definition also picks $\delta$ after getting the $\varepsilon$, right?

In quantors (using $\mathcal{U}_x$ for the set of open neighbourhoods of $x$ in a space) continuity of $f$ at $p \in X$ becomes:

$$\forall V \in \mathcal{U}_{f(p)}: \exists U \in \mathcal{U}_p: f[U] \subseteq V$$

Comment: Terrific answer! I catch the meaning!